# Does wicket has any Drag and drop component

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, persistence, wicket

I have 5-6 containers which I want to drag and drop across the viewable window.

Comment: Isn't this [wicketstuff Dojo Drag and drop example](http://wicketstuff.org/wicketdojo13/?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.wicketstuff.dojo.examples.dnd.DnDShower) what you are looking for? I haven't looked into it but colleagues used it as inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

Not on it's own but there are several jquery integrations to provide this functionality.

Comment: Thanks... i did followed this link http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/05/implement-drag-and-drop-example-jquery-javascript-html.html  this is simple and basic way to drag a component however still i have one more question as how can i interchange the one component . say if i drag Panel A on Panel B .Then A should take the position of B and B should move somewhere else or take the position of A .. Could you please let me know how this can be done in Jquery and wicket

Comment: You might be looking for jQuery [Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) instead of Drag and Drop

Answer (score 1):

There are two interesting Wicket integrations for such stuff:

- wicket-dnd: https://github.com/svenmeier/wicket-dnd
- wicket-select2: https://github.com/ivaynberg/wicket-select2

I use both and am pleased with them, they both work with Wicket 6 and the Wicket jquery integration.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Wicket has such functionality in its wicket-ajax.js. It is being used by wicket-ajax-debug.js - the code used by the floating Ajax Debug window that you can see in DEVELOPMENT mode. But I also recommend to use the DnD functionality provided by the JavaScript library that use eventually use in your project.